# If Then between two sheets with message box

Tags: vba, excel

The sheet I'm working on is a task management sheet with a list of open, pending and completed items. I've created a drop down menu which a person can change the status of a task but I want to automate the process so that a completed task will cut the row over to a new sheet to the end of a completed task table and the original sheet will shift up one row. In addition, I wanted to include two message boxes (one that asks the date the task was completed and the other that prompts if there are any comments related to the task) that after copying the row of data to the new sheet, would add two new data points in the two adjacent cells.

In theory, the macro would be: if a cell in column F = "Completed", then highlight from C:H of that row (this is the first problem I ran into with offsetting the selection to cut), cut the data and paste it into the first blank row (into column B) of the new sheet. After, the two message boxes prompting the date of completion and notes on the task would pop and the values entered in there would paste into column F and G of the new sheet respectively.

I started with a basic if and then statement but was stopped by the coding for offsetting (kept getting a 1004 error) the selection of data to cut.

Comment: Please show some code samples as well, it is hard to answer what exactly is wrong with your macro otherwise, and why are you getting that error. Oh, and welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: @Jeeped I think by "highlight" OP means "select"

Comment: Thanks @JohnColeman - I think you're right.

Answer (score 1):

So here is a quick and dirty, brute force method of doing the following:

-Search through column f on sheet1
    -if 'Complete' is found, cut/copy contents to row two on sheet2 (inserting them so previous items shift down and using row two since row 1 is typically headers), then delete row with 'complete' on sheet1
    -Have input message boxes in this process to get Completion date and any notes and put that data into sheet2 columns f and g respectively.

The above is what I am reading your request to be. The code below probably has some unnecessary sheet selects and you might want to put the data into g and h since I'm not sure if you actually would want to overwrite the contents of column f that was just pasted. But the below should be close to what you would want.

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim DateComplete As Variant
Dim Notes As Variant

i = 2 'variable for iterating through sheet1

While Sheet1.Cells(i, 6).Value <> "" 'do while column f is not empty
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select 'Make sure sheet 1 is selected
    If Cells(i, 6).Value = "Complete" Then
        'Insert new row in sheet2
        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        Rows("2:2").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

        'copy desired cells from sheet1
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        Range("C" & i & ":H" & i).Copy

        'Go back to sheet2 and paste rows into row 2
        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        Range("A2").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste

        'input box for date with syntax for possible task name reference with default date set to today
        DateComplete = InputBox("Enter Date Complete For task " & Cells(i, 3).Value, "Completion Date", Format(Now(), "yyyy/mm/dd"))
        Notes = InputBox("Enter Notes", "Notes")

        'input values from message boxes into f2 and g2
        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        Range("F2").Value = DateComplete
        Range("G2").Value = Notes

        'Go to sheet1 and delete row that was just copied from
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        Rows(i & ":" & i).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Else
        i = i + 1 'i only needs to be iterated if complete is not found
    End If
Wend
response = MsgBox("Done", vbOKOnly)
```

If completed records are desired to be put in the first open row in sheet2 as opposed to inserting them on line two then use the following code:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim x as Integer
Dim DateComplete As Variant
Dim Notes As Variant

i = 2 'variable for iterating through sheet1
x = 1
'Find first blank row in column a on sheet2
While Sheet2.Cells(x, 6).Value <> ""
    x = x + 1
Wend
'x is now set to first blank row in sheet2

While Sheet1.Cells(i, 6).Value <> "" 'do while column f is not empty
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select 'Make sure sheet 1 is selected
    If Cells(i, 6).Value = "Complete" Then
        'copy desired cells from sheet1
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        Range("C" & i & ":H" & i).Copy

        'Go back to sheet2 and paste rows into row x
        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        Range("A" & x).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste

        'input box for date with syntax for possible task name reference with default date set to today
        DateComplete = InputBox("Enter Date Complete For task " & Cells(i, 3).Value, "Completion Date", Format(Now(), "yyyy/mm/dd"))
        Notes = InputBox("Enter Notes", "Notes")

        'input values from message boxes into f2 and g2
        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        Range("F" & x).Value = DateComplete
        Range("G" & x).Value = Notes

        'Go to sheet1 and delete row that was just copied from
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        Rows(i & ":" & i).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        x = x + 1
    Else
        i = i + 1 'i only needs to be iterated if complete is not found
    End If
Wend
response = MsgBox("Done", vbOKOnly)
```

Comment: Hu, thank you so much for your help. It works perfectly. However, one quick question. If I wanted the message copy and pasting to paste into the first available vacant cell or row, how would the code change?

for example, it pastes into B2 and the message boxes paste into f2 and g2 but what would the code be to paste into the first available row in B and into the first available cells in f and g?

Comment: So you want on sheet2 to past the rows into the first blank row and then do the same for f and g even though that might disassociate the contents of f and g from the other pasted content? Or are you asking for all of those to be pasted on the first blank row instead of into row two as I do above?